# What is the pendant of icacls /inheritance:r in C#

Tags: c#, active-directory

I would need to disable file system permission inheritance for a particular folder, what I found was that `icacls "..." /inheritance:r` does exactly what I would like to acchieve.

Can anybody tell me how to perform this in C# without calling icacls?

Thank's in advance

Answer (score 0):

While tinkering with the code I found out that

```
accessControl.SetAccessRuleProtection(true, false);
```

disables the inheritance.